# Как закрасить ячейки в JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Таблица заполняется 0 и 1.
Нужно закрашивать ячейку в JTable другим цветом, если в ячейке записана 1.
У меня пока получилось закрасить всю строку.
Код ниже.

Класс JTable:

```
public class JTableExample {

JTable jTable;
TabModel  tModel;
ArrayList tableDatas;
Renderer renderer = new Renderer();

JTableExample() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Printer Imitation");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Введите строки матрицы");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

    JButton buttonAdd = new JButton("Ввод");
    JButton buttonDel = new JButton("Очистить");

    buttonAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            String values = textField.getText().replaceAll("\\s", "");
            String[] strValues = values.split(",");

            tableDatas.add(new TableData(strValues[0], strValues[1], strValues[2], strValues[3], strValues[4],
                    strValues[5], strValues[6], strValues[7], strValues[8], strValues[9], strValues[10]));
            tModel.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    });

    buttonDel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tModel.clearHistory();
            textField.setText("");
        }
    });

    tableDatas = new ArrayList();
    tModel = new TabModel(tableDatas);
    jTable = new JTable(tModel);

    for (int i = 0; i < jTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(renderer);
        jTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 145));

        frame.add(jTable);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.add(buttonAdd);
        frame.add(buttonDel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JTableExample();
        }
    });
}}
```

Класс Renderer:

```
public class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                               Object value,
                                               boolean isSelected,
                                               boolean hasFocus,
                                               int row,
                                               int column) {
   Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    String cellvalue = table.getValueAt(row, table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("1")).toString();
    if(cellvalue.equals("1")){cell.setBackground(Color.RED);}
    return cell;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компонент `cell` всегда один и тот же объект, поэтому ему надо задавать цвет каждый раз:

```
if (cellvalue.equals("1")) {
    cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
} else {
    cell.setBackground(table.getBackground());
}
```

Если нужно покрасить только ячейки с единицей, то вот этот код выбирает значение ячейки в колонке с именем `"1"`:

```
String cellvalue = table.getValueAt(row, table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("1")).toString();
```

и его нужно заменить на

```
String cellvalue = value.toString();
```

Параметр метода `value` содержит значение текущей ячейки.

Comment: Вводил для примера: 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0. Цвет не изменился. Ставится тот цвет, что в блоке else. Опять же на всю строку, а не на конкретные ячейки.

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо!